# Why I cannot install a module from PyPI using pip but I can install it using easy_install?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, fitnesse, pypi

I am trying to install [waferslim](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/waferslim) (A python port of the fitnesse slim server and protocols) into my python environment. Waferslim is in the Python package library PyPI, however when I try to install it using pip it doesn't work, I get a package not found error:

```
(test) C:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\test\Scripts>pip install waferslim
Downloading/unpacking waferslim
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement waferslim
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for waferslim
```

But if I try installing it with easy_install, it is installed correctly. Why does this happen? Is there a way I can install it using Pip instead of easy_install? I wrote a requirements.txt file that holds all the dependencies for my project, but running `pip install -r requirements.txt` fails because of waferslim.

Comment: what does `pip search waferslim` say? what version of setuptools are you using?

Comment: @njzk2 Using `pip search waferslim` gives this error: `[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. An the setuptools version is 2.2.